# How to add inputs of the correct widget type to the page?

Tags: visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

I have a an object that defines attributes and the type of attribute; for instance `Nme` (String), `LastSeenDate__c` (Date), `Age` (Number), `Countries` (Picklist), etc.

Based on this information, I want to build a `Visualforce Page` where a Date field is displayed with a date picker, a picklist field is displayed as selectOptions, and so on.

To make things more interesting, this should be a list. This means that the 1st row will show "Name" and accept "STRING" from user, the second row may show "LastSeenDate" and show date picker.

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Visualforce provides the [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) dedicated to this.

Comment: As Martin Lenzer notes, `<apex:inputField>` is the tool for the job here. Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use that? If you're looking for a way to add a collection of `sObject` fields to a Visualforce page without typing `<apex:inputField>` over and over, you should take a look at [using fieldsets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm)

Comment: How do I use inputField? I could not find a way to render dropdown list if the type of the field is dropdown. I could use type=data etc. Can you please provide me some pointers?

Comment: There's an example in the documentation I provided.

Comment: @vetal_king the idea here is that you'd use an `SObject` (like `Account`) that has field(s) of the appropriate type (from your example, `Text`, `Date`, `Number`, and `Picklist`, respectively) instead of using your custom object (which is the 'hard way' of accomplishing what you're looking to do).

Comment: Thanks Martin, Derek for your response. Yes I am trying to build the VF page based on metadata information that is present in one of the custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this is exactly how [`<apex:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) works.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.Last_Seen_Date__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.Age__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.Country__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.Countries__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshots**

Date Picker:

[image: Date Picker]

Picklist:

[image: Picklist]

**Field Sets**

You can also very easily move these fields to a configurable list using a `Field Set`. You still won't even need `Apex`.

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.FieldSets.Demo}" var="field">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c[field]}" />
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```